# Views Block: one node latest of several categories

Tags: views, nodes

Is it possible to do with the views I had one recent node of the 5 categories?
example:
- Category 1 (20 node)
- Category 2 (10 node)
- Category 3 (5 node)
- Category 4 (17 node)
- Category 5 (2 node)

VIEWS BLOCK:

- Newest node (category 1) only one!
- Newest node (category 2) only one!
- Newest node (category 3) only one!
- Newest node (category 4) only one!
- Newest node (category 5) only one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator).

Create a view with fields category (hidden if you like), and title. Sort first by category, and secondly by post date descending.

Set the format of the view to 'Table with aggregation options'. In the settings for that format, select 'Apply group function' for category, and in the dropdown that appears select 'Group and Compress'.

Remove the pager and display all items.

[image]

Comment: yes yes! THX!! this is it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a normal view first listing only the newest item (see Pager settings).
Then, create a contextual filter for the category so that you can call the view with different category ids.

Now, you'll the [Views Field View module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view), it enables you to add other views as fields. Add a View Field Views field for each category to your block display.